# Use a subset of methods as member methods in different classes in C#

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture, mixins

Is it possible to use a subset of methods as member methods in different classes in C#?

For instance, I have four functions the `void A()`, the `void B()`, the `void C()` and the `void D()`.

And now I want to have three classes. The first class I would like to have the member methods `A`, `B` and `C`. The second I would like to have the `B` and `D`. And the third the `A`, `C` and `D`.

How could I achieve this? Is it possible to achieve this only by using interfaces or are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your three classes should have **different implementations** for these methods, then classic interfaces are the way to go:

```cs
public interface IHaveA {
    void A();
}

public interface IHaveB {
    void B();
}

public interface IHaveC {
    void C();
}

public interface IHaveD {
    void D();
}

public class Class1 : IHaveA, IHaveB, IHaveC { // Implement A, B and C here }

public class Class2 : IHaveB, IHaveD { // Implement B and D here  }

public class Class3 : IHaveA, IHaveC, IHaveD { // Implement A, C and D here  }
```

If all your classes should have the **same implementation of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`**, you could still use interfaces but you would have to duplicate code:

```cs
public static class StaticImplementation {
    public void A(IHaveA sender) {
        // Do stuff here
    }

    public void B(IHaveB sender) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
    public void C(IHaveC sender) {
        // Do stuff here
    }

    public void D(IHaveD sender) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}

public class Class1 : IHaveA, IHaveB, IHaveC {
    public void A() { StaticImplementation.A(this) }
    public void B() { StaticImplementation.B(this) }
    public void C() { StaticImplementation.C(this) }
}

public class Class2 : IHaveB, IHaveD { // Calls to StaticImplementation for B and D here  }

public class Class3 : IHaveA, IHaveC, IHaveD { // Calls to StaticImplementation for A, C and D here  }
```

There is no way to enforce that these three classes have the same implementation of these methods using interfaces, because the primary goal interfaces is to ensure that classes implement methods, specifically with different implementations!

**This changes in C# 8.0 and .NET Core 3.0** where you can have default implementations for interface methods, and you could ensure that these implementations do not change by sealing them.

The code would become:

```cs
public interface IHaveA {
    sealed void A() {
        // Implementation here
    }
}

public interface IHaveB {
    sealed void B() {
        // Implementation here
    }
}

public interface IHaveC {
    sealed void C() {
        // Implementation here
    }
}

public interface IHaveD {
    sealed void D() {
        // Implementation here
    }
}

public class Class1 : IHaveA, IHaveB, IHaveC { // Nothing to do here }

public class Class2 : IHaveB, IHaveD { // Nothing to do here  }

public class Class3 : IHaveA, IHaveC, IHaveD { // Nothing to do here  }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Could you, please, comment on my answer below? I am accepting your answer as the best, but still curious what you may think about mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public interface MA {}
public static class MAProvider {
    public static void A(this MA obj) { Console.WriteLine("MA"); }
}

public interface MB {}
public static class MBProvider {
    public static void B(this MB obj) { Console.WriteLine("MB"); }
}

public interface MC {}
public static class MCProvider {
    public static void C(this MC obj) { Console.WriteLine("MC"); }
}

public interface MD {}
public static class MDProvider {
    public static void D(this MD obj) { Console.WriteLine("MD"); }
}

public class First : MA, MB, MC {}
public class Second : MB, MD {}
public class Third : MA, MC, MD {}

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        new First().A();
        new First().B();
        new First().C();

        new Second().B();
        new Second().D();

        new Third().A();
        new Third().C();
        new Third().D();
    }
}
```

The only issue which is left is the `private` members. Since we can not access them inside the extension methods.

Comment: Yeah, this is actually very similar to my own answer because extension methods are nothing more than static methods, like I suggest to do with my `StaticImplementation`. But if you can afford to use C#8 and .NET Core 3.0, default implementations are the best idea imho:)

Comment: @CorentinPane, do the default interface implementation allow to use the `private` members?

Comment: no, there is still no way for interfaces to have private member instances. You cannot either access a class private fields from another interface, it would ruin the principle of `private`. Maybe you can define a public property in your interfaces, and this property would ``get`` a private member when implemented?